# How to Read csv files and store header in Map<header, List<values>> using Java?

Tags: java, csv

I have large csv files data with its header. I want to store those data header and columns values in a `Map<String, List<Object>>`, i am new to Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filename), ',', '"', 1);
        String[] header = csvReader.readNext();
        List<String[]> arr = csvReader.readAll();

        Map<String, List<Object>> tableandcols = new HashMap<String, List<Object>>();
        arr.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

             ////do something
        }

        System.out.println(tableandcols);
    }
```